# Actualizar variable cada vez que se actualice esa variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy consultando datos de una api mediante PHP, en donde quiero que la variable $clima se cambie automáticamente, cuando ya no tenga el mismo valor que tenia antes, y que se muestre que se muestre la variable clima ya actualizada,  todo esto sin actualizar toda la pagina, solo la variable clima.

```html
$url ="";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$clima =  json_decode($clima,true);

//var_dump($ticker);
echo "Libro";
?><br><?
echo $clima['clima'][0]['grados'];
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stakoverflow. Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. Lo único que se entiende es que quieres actualizar unos datos desde una API sin tener que refrescar la página. La forma habitual de hacer esto es con Ajax. Según se ve, ni siquiera necesitas PHP para esto, puedes hacerlo desde Javascript.

Comment: Exacto, pero como hago el codigo con ajax.

Comment: Quieres que se actualice sola sin ningun evento como el click? o quieres que se actualice después de un evento click u otro evento que el usuario controle?

Comment: Exacto que se actualice sola

Answer (score -1, accepted):

setInterval(funcion_refrescar(), 30000);//cada 30 segundos

Comment: Hola Santiakus. Gracias por aportar pero para que la respuesta sea de calidad has de explicar mejor su funcionamiento. Mira [answer] y [tour] para más info. Un saludo